# Unable to get the metrics from PostgreSQL in RHEL 7 using MetricBeat

Tags: postgresql, rhel7, metricbeat

I'm unable to get the metrics from PostgreSQL in RHEL 7 using MetricBeat

Postgres Version 11

MetricBeat Version 7.8

I have also added/removed the credentials.

Below I have shared the error

module/wrapper.go: "259" Error fetching data for metrics..."postgres"

Do we need to provide any permission or configuration missing

Here below the configuration for Postgres module

```
- module: postgresql
  metricsets:
    - database
    - bgwriter
    - activity
  period: 10s
  hosts: ["postgres://localhost:5432?sslmode=disable"]
  username: postgres
  password: ********
```

Detail Log

```
Aug 13 11:04:01 HOSTNAME metricbeat[94021]: 2020-08-13T11:04:01.647+0530        INFO        module/wrapper.go:259        Error fetching data for metricset postgresql.activity: error in QueryStats: failed to obtain a connection with the database: pq: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
Aug 13 11:04:01 HOSTNAME metricbeat[94021]: 2020-08-13T11:04:01.667+0530        INFO        module/wrapper.go:259        Error fetching data for metricset postgresql.bgwriter: error in QueryStats: failed to obtain a connection with the database: pq: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
Aug 13 11:04:01 HOSTNAME metricbeat[94021]: 2020-08-13T11:04:01.668+0530        INFO        module/wrapper.go:259        Error fetching data for metricset postgresql.database: error in QueryStats: failed to obtain a connection with the database: pq: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
Aug 13 11:04:11 HOSTNAME metricbeat[94021]: 2020-08-13T11:04:11.648+0530        INFO        module/wrapper.go:259        Error fetching data for metricset postgresql.activity: error in QueryStats: failed to obtain a connection with the database: pq: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
Aug 13 11:04:11 HOSTNAME metricbeat[94021]: 2020-08-13T11:04:11.667+0530        INFO        module/wrapper.go:259        Error fetching data for metricset postgresql.bgwriter: error in QueryStats: failed to obtain a connection with the database: pq: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
Aug 13 11:04:11 HOSTNAME metricbeat[94021]: 2020-08-13T11:04:11.668+0530        INFO        module/wrapper.go:259        Error fetching data for metricset postgresql.database: error in QueryStats: failed to obtain a connection with the database: pq: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
Aug 13 11:04:19 HOSTNAME metricbeat[94021]: 2020-08-13T11:04:19.936+0530        INFO        [monitoring]        log/log.go:145        Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":84510,"time":{"ms":844}},"total":{"ticks":150820,"time":{"ms":1498},"value":150820},
                                                    "user":{"ticks":66310,"time":{"ms":654}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":4096,"soft":1024},"open":28},
                                                    "info":{"ephemeral_id":"62200651-b30e-4b7f-8048-04f9fbb57055","uptime":{"ms":3270201}},
                                                    "memstats":{"gc_next":23756848,"memory_alloc":22309400,"memory_total":10172710312,"rss":4096},
                                                    "runtime":{"goroutines":163}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0}},
                                                    "output":{"events":{"acked":111,"batches":6,"total":111}},
                                                    "pipeline":{"clients":22,"events":{"active":0,"published":111,"total":111},"queue":{"acked":111}}},
                                                    "metricbeat":{"docker":{"container":{"events":6,"success":6},"cpu":{"events":6,"success":6},
                                                    "diskio":{"events":6,"success":6},"image":{"events":6,"success":6},"info":{"events":3,"success":3},
                                                    "memory":{"events":6,"success":6},"network":{"events":6,"success":6}},"postgresql":{"activity":{"events":3,"failures":3},
                                                    "bgwriter":{"events":3,"failures":3},"database":{"events":3,"failures":3}},"system":{"cpu":{"events":3,"success":3},
                                                    "load":{"events":3,"success":3},"memory":{"events":3,"success":3},"network":{"events":21,"success":21},
                                                    "process":{"events":27,"success":27},"process_summary":{"events":3,"success":3},"socket_summary":{"events":3,"success":3}}},
                                                    "system":{"load":{"1":0.06,"15":0.06,"5":0.08,"norm":{"1":0.015,"15":0.015,"5":0.02}}}}}}
Aug 13 11:04:21 HOSTNAME metricbeat[94021]: 2020-08-13T11:04:21.647+0530        INFO        module/wrapper.go:259        Error fetching data for metricset postgresql.activity: error in QueryStats: failed to obtain a connection with the database: pq: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
Aug 13 11:04:21 HOSTNAME metricbeat[94021]: 2020-08-13T11:04:21.667+0530        INFO        module/wrapper.go:259        Error fetching data for metricset postgresql.database: error in QueryStats: failed to obtain a connection with the database: pq: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
Aug 13 11:04:21 HOSTNAME metricbeat[94021]: 2020-08-13T11:04:21.669+0530        INFO        module/wrapper.go:259        Error fetching data for metricset postgresql.bgwriter: error in QueryStats: failed to obtain a connection with the database: pq: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Could somebody help me out on this

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect with this host connection string format

> [postgres://][user:pass@]host[:port][?options]

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-module-postgresql.html